# how to show popup from Web-view in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am getting a data from url . I am showing in a Web-view Everything fine,but my requirement is i want to add references functionality like it wikipedia as shown in image . In Wikipedia when click that tag it scroll down to that position but now my requirement is when user click on that reference i want to show popup . Is It possible?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of **UIWebViewDelegate** method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

This will be called before the web view begins loading.

Here argument `UIWebViewNavigationType` is an enum, which holds the value of the navigation type, check whether the navigationType is `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`. If Yes that means webView is loading page because of any of the link is clicked.

Code will look something like this

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"url" message:[[request URL] absoluteString] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: if i write this method data is not loading in web-view

Comment: return YES from this method

Comment: @Ganeshmanoj This method will be called when any link in the web page is tapped.

Comment: ok i written the same but i wrote else condition with return NO . so i think while loading its going to NO..

Comment: Thank you i return NO so i got that problem now everything fine . Got my requirement.

Comment: Yes, while loading navigationType is `UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther`